# Supporting Multiple Screens In Google Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I just created a project with google api build target (API level 3) in order to use the google.android.maps library. The problem now is I only have 1 drawable folder in res while I should have 3 (which is the case when I create a project with android 1.5 build target).

How can I create a project that has the google maps library and 3 resource folders? Maybe create a regular project and manually import the maps.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your android SDK version to 1.6 (Google apis lvl 4 or higher). There's only 1 drawable folder in 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply create the folders manually.

Comment: But then they probably won't be used as device specifik resource folders?

Comment: I won't say this, as you mentioned that you got 3 folders when you use the standard 1.5 Android framework without the Google API. So why should the standard 1.5 framework use 3 folders whereas the 1.5 framework with Google API only uses one. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: AFAIK, standard 1.5 framework uses only 1 folder, so mb Vincent was wrong.